# How to make NSMutableArray persistent in this case?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios7.1

I have gone through the related and similar questions but I found that the requirements in those questions were more complex and different than mine. I have a simple `NSMutableArray` which consists of `MKPolyline` objects (around 17000). I want to know how can I store this data in the most efficient and least time taking manner (for retrieval).

I tried the following though:

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];

// append our file name
NSURL *url = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"trailLines1.data" isDirectory:NO];
trailLines1 = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url] mutableCopy];           
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL2 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];


// append our file name
NSURL *url2 = [documentsDirectoryURL2 URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"trailLines2.data" isDirectory:NO];           
trailLines2 = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url] mutableCopy];
```

`trailLines1` and `trailLines2` are `NSMutableArray` object containing `MKPolyline` Objects. But here when I try to retrieve the data, I get nil.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's a problem with the data you are loading from. I think it needs to be in a valid plist format. Can you post that too?

I would also double check that the URLs you are getting is valid. Add some more log statements.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html

Comment: I will try your suggestion out and reply in a short while. Thanks.